# Mysql triggers to copy data from one table to other when a value is inserted

Tags: mysql, triggers

I would like to do a trigger for when a user edit their profile (***profile_data***) adding the country on the field "Value" that value will be written on ***player_profile*** on the flag field and add a .gif at the end. The uid2 value goes to the uid2 flag

profile_data

```
ID    uid   Value
1      2     uk
2      1     esp
```

player_profile

```
uid       flag
 1      uk.gif
 2      esp.gif
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_user_insert AFTER INSERT ON profile_data
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO player_profile (flag)
```

But I don't know what to write more

Comment: Why don't you just derive the `flag` from `Value` with `concat(Value, '.gif') as flag` and save yourself a lot of troubles by dealing with triggers?

Comment: And I can go catch the value on the other table and insert it on Flag with a concat? because they are in different tables and the user will insert the value on profile_data table

Comment: What I mean is that you shouldn't have the  `player_profile` table at all, because its content is redundant. Maintaining redundant data is quite complex and can easily lead to bugs. You probably didn't think about that you will need triggers for inserts, updates and deletes.